# Can't find created file

Tags: android, file

I'm writing my little app for Android. I'm trying to create files. Here is a code snippet:

```
final String TESTSTRING = new String("Hello Android");                 
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("samplefile.txt",Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 
osw.write(TESTSTRING);
osw.flush();
osw.close();

FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput("samplefile.txt");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
char[] inputBuffer = new char[TESTSTRING.length()];

isr.read(inputBuffer);

String readString = new String(inputBuffer);

boolean isTheSame = TESTSTRING.equals(readString);

if(isTheSame) {
    TextView mLat=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    mLat.setText(String.valueOf(isTheSame));     
}
```

I can't find this created samplefile.txt using file manager.
Can anyone tell me the path where app is writing?

ok now i have this:

```
String pathToExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
     File appDirectory = new File(pathToExternalStorage + "/" + "testowa", "new_file.txt");
     try{
         OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(appDirectory);
         os.write(pathToExternalStorage.getBytes());
         os.flush();
         os.close();
     }
     catch(IOException e)
     {

     }
```

Exception Thrown on OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(appDirectory);
Cant find why.
i modified manifest with permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is created in `/data/data/your.package.name/files`. However, this directory is not visible for file mangagers (unless they have root rights).

Comment: So if i want files to be visible for users, I will need to use external drive?

Comment: Yes, have a look at `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`, it returns the directory where you can put the externally visible files.

Answer (score 1):

The file is located in /data/data/com.yourpackagename/files/filename.txt which is hidden unless the device is rooted. You can access the file by copying it from the directory where it is created.

From the command line:

To copy a file

```
    adb -d shell 
    run-as com.yourpackagename 
    cat /data/data/com.yourpackagename/files/filename.txt > /sdcard/filename.txt
```

Alternatively for a SQLite database

```
    cat /data/data/com.yourpackagename/databases/dbname.db > /sdcard/dbname.sqlite
```

This solution will work without having to root the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path of the files created using `openFileOutput(name)` using [`getFileStreamPath(name)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFileStreamPath%28java.lang.String%29). But file manager apps will need root privileges to view this path.